When the rhyme scheme is ABAB, can A=B or is that insanity?
Hear me out. My default answer is no, no it cannot. The very definition of a rhyme scheme requires that the different letters represent different rhyming sounds. However, in every standard definition I have come across, this is not explicitly stated. A rhyme scheme of ABBA means that the first and fourth line must rhyme, and the second and third must rhyme, as everyone knows, but nowhere have I seen a definition to also specify that the first and fourth lines cannot and must not rhyme with the second and third. I take this omission to be evidence of the obvious. However I am in a heated debate with someone who insists otherwise and I am seeking sources. Where can I find in the reputable annals of formal verse that definition which states what a rhyme scheme both requires and forbids? Hard evidence that it's not a limerick if all the lines rhyme? Or by all means tell me I'm wrong, please.

Rhyme schemes aren't maths, and A and B aren't variables that may have the same value.
Metzler Lexikon Literatur: Begriffe und Definitionen, a German standard dictionary for literary terms, edited by Dieter Burdorf, Christoph Fasbender, and Burkhard Moennighoff (3rd ed., 2007, p. 640) states that "identical lowercase letters represent corresponding sounds" (my translation) while capital letters represent identically repeated words or verses. Thus the triolet has the scheme ABaAabAB. By implication, different letters mean different sounds and words.
The Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms by Chris Baldick (4th ed., 2015, s.v. rhyme scheme) explains that a rhyme scheme is "the pattern in which the rhymed line-endings are arranged in a poem or stanza. This may be expressed as a sequence of recurrences in which each line ending on the same rhyme is given the same alphabetic symbol". Again, by implication, different alphabetic symbols mean different rhymes.
Encyclopedia Britannica (s.v. rhyme scheme, https://www.britannica.com/art/rhyme-scheme) is more explicit. It states that "the rhyme scheme is usually notated with lowercase letters of the alphabet ..., each different letter representing a different rhyme" (my emphasis).
So there you have it. A definition that explicitly says a and b must be different.
If that is not enough, you can also think about it logically. Since scholars distinguish the rhyme schemes abab (cross rhyme), abba (enclosed rhyme), aabb (two couplets), and aaaa (monorhyme), these must be different. If all of the mentioned rhyme schemes may be aaaa, distinguishing them doesn't make any sense.
Finally, the rhyme scheme that you and your friend are debating, represented as abab, is called an alternate or crossed rhyme. "A cross rhyme is a variation of a tail rhyme in which the rhyming lines alternate, such as the first line rhyming with the third line and the second line rhyming with the fourth line." (Grammarly) I'm sure you will both agree that there is nothing crossed or alternating in aaaa.

I think, by definition/logic, that the only way to correctly understand 'ABAB' or 'ABBA' is that those different words do, indeed, not rhyme across both A's and B's... Otherwise, you'd simply have 'AAAA'.
I think that's the only way to read or understand rhyme schemes in general. If you make something rhyme 'more' than 'ABAB' you're simply using another scheme.

You're describing it with so many words and yet the question is still ambiguous.
If you're asking whether, when analysing a poem that has the scheme of AAAA, you can describe it as ABAB, then no. Calling it ABAB, or ABBA, or AABB, are all weaker claims than called for. You wouldn't characterise it as ABCD and claim it's metric without rhymes, would you? So, take all the rhymes into account.
If you're asking whether, when writing a poem that's otherwise ABAB, you can throw in a verse of AAAA, then... the answer is, in most cases you can't because the length and ending of the lines doesn't allow it.

Shall I compare thee to a summer morning,
or should I rather use a winter day?
In either case, I'm giving you a warning:
You'll turn into and be the thing I say.

...Good luck with turning this into AAAA.
If the metric structure isn't an obstacle, you can do it, but whether it will be more or rather less aesthetically pleasing than if you kept the two pairs of rhymes different is an open question. I'd venture a guess and say it's more likely it'll be less pleasing if you do it in the middle of an otherwise ABAB poem.
I'm not sure what a limerick is doing in the question, because limericks never use ABAB in the first place.
And sure, I can imagine a limerick along these lines of form...

There was a lady like you, my friend,
asking her questions just without end.
I know you may tend
to have days to spend
but can't say it's something I'd recommend.

  - but if I were to analyse it, I'd still assign the standard AABBA scheme to it, for rhytmical reasons.
If it's an assigned exercise to write ABAB, don't make the two the same, or you'll be marked as not understanding the assignment.
